# Hiding repeated rows in telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm attempting to hide duplicate cell values for specific columns in  a Telerik RadGrid.

I attempted to use the code below which does not work. Stepping through the code with the debugger, I can see where it appears to be making the right decisions. I am wondering then if the method I'm using to update the cell in incorrect or of I'm missing some important step.

```
private void HideGridDuplicates(RadGrid radGrid, string[] fieldNames)
    {
        var hashLastValues = new Hashtable();

        foreach (string fieldName in fieldNames)
        {

            foreach (GridDataItem item in radGrid.Items)
            {
                string currentValue = item.GetDataKeyAsString(fieldName); 
                if (hashLastValues.ContainsKey(fieldName))
                    if ((string)hashLastValues[fieldName] == currentValue)
                        currentValue = "";
                    else
                        hashLastValues[fieldName] = currentValue;
                else
                    hashLastValues.Add(fieldName, currentValue);

                item[fieldName].Text = currentValue;
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: What is populating the RadGrid? I feel that you could filter it before the grid gets databound

Comment: That seems to be the general consensus. It's a collection generated with LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This should be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT ExpenseID, ClaimID, [Description],TransactionDate
FROM (SELECT ExpenseID, ClaimID, [Description],TransactionDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClaimID ORDER BY expenseID) rn
        FROM Expense) t
        WHERE rn = 1;
```

I have just tested this on my own test database and i think this is what you are trying to achieve. if you change the "PARTITION BY ClaimID" this will change to the column you need.

Comment: Some rows were duplicated, some weren't